# Confusion matrix in Weka

Tags: weka, confusion-matrix

I want to calculate confusion matrix, f1 score, roc etc. But the Weka output is showing this. How can I get the confusion matrix, f1 score, roc, etc?

[image: Weka output]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your dataset seems to have a numeric class attribute. `Correlation coefficient` is a statistic generated for regression models. A confusion matrix (which you want) is only computed for classification models.

Secondly, you are using [ZeroR](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/rules/ZeroR.html) as classifier, which is not a very useful classifier (only for determining a baseline). ZeroR either predicts the mean class value (numeric class attribute) or the majority class (nominal class attribute).

**Solutions:**

1. Ensure that you are using the right attribute for your class. Assuming that you are using the Weka Explorer, check the combobox on the *Classify* panel that it has the right attribute selected. On the command-line, use the `-c` flag to specify the index of the class attribute (1-based index, `first` and `last` can be used as well).
2. If you imported your data from a CSV file and the class attribute column contains only numeric values, then Weka will have left it as numeric (it doesn't know that this column represents a nominal attribute). In that case, make sure that you convert your class attribute to a nominal one, e.g., by using the [NumericToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NumericToNominal.html) filter in the `Preprocess` panel.
3. Choose a different classifier, like [RandomForest](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html) or [J48](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html), which tend to generate reasonable models with just the default parameters.